# Azure Service Bus in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm using Service Bus trigger in Azure Functions v2.0. In the previous version i have used Brokered Message and there are no problems with this. But as i moved to v2.0 i need to use Message instead of Brokered Message. And once i called

```
await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
```

i get an exception which says:

> The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue, or was received by a different receiver instance.
>   I have configured my Queue Client as follows:

```
var queueClient = new QueueClient(serviceBusString, MessageQueueName);
```

Does anyone face this issue? Are there any workarounds ?

Answer (score 1):

Incoming messages that trigger Function execution are automatically completed when function is done. You do not need to complete those messages yourself. The exception you see is indicating that.